# echo statement repeats

Tags: plugin-development, the-content

Creating first wp plugin.

Using add action init with filter for the_content

I noticed that whenever I echo anything it appears twice in the header, and finally once in the body.

Why?

Or How can I avoid this?

kthxbai

**EDIT**

```
function my_module_init() {
  //Filter this content
  add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_ctrlr');
}
add_action('init', 'my_module_init');

// function controller plug-in
function my_content_ctrlr($content) {
  global $post;

//Get value of metabox from current id
  $codeUnit = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'list_unit_meta_key', true); 

//If none selected from metabox, skip it as its a regular page
  if( $codeUnit == 'NULL' || !isset($codeUnit) || $codeUnit == '') {
    return $content;
  }

//if I add echo anything, it shows up twice in head and once in body
//  WHY?
//echo $codeUnit;

    ob_start(); 

    //If photo included display grid view, else table view
    if  ($includePhoto == 'on') {
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'views/my-grid.php');
    } else {
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'views/my-table.php');
    }

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;

}
```

Comment: Please post your code. It sounds like you might be echoing from within the `the_content` filter callback (which is not the way to go, you want to use return) but it's hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Let me post a whittled back version as there is a lot of code. I'm calling a service, and have multiple views, based on metabox values, but I've tested a few scenarios and it really seems to be something todo with wordpress. For now I have offset the effects with object buffer. But there must be some explanation for this behaviour!

Comment: thanks  @goto10, as I mentioned I can offset the echo from within `the_content` by using object buffer, but I get the impression that this same process is affecting my service fetch performance, like x3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that the root issue exists within the code provided. I tested an even further reduced test case which I've pasted below, and I do not get duplicated content:

```
function my_module_init() {
  add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_ctrlr');
}
add_action('init', 'my_module_init');

function my_content_ctrlr( $content ) {
    ob_start(); 

    // This file contains only the following simple text for testing purposes: #########    
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'views/my-grid.php' ); 

    $output = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    // Add our custom code before the existing content.
    return $output . $content;
}
```

So, I think that we can rule out my original idea that content was being echoed instead of returned.

Another possibility is that there are additional `apply_filters()` calls on `the_content` somewhere in your site via plugins or the theme. E.g.:

```
echo ( apply_filters( 'the_content', '<div>Hello there!</div>' ) );
```

It's not uncommon for themes to do that kind of thing, and it would result in `my_content_ctrlr()` being called once for each additional occurrence.

You can use some additional checks as illustrated by this snippet to resolve that problem ([source](https://pippinsplugins.com/playing-nice-with-the-content-filter/)).

```
function pippin_filter_content_sample($content) {
    if( is_singular() && is_main_query() ) {
        $new_content = '<p>This is added to the bottom of all post and page content, as well as custom post types.</p>';
        $content .= $new_content;   
    }   
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'pippin_filter_content_sample');
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @goto10, the `is_main_query` didn't work for me but set me in the right direction, adding additional conditional checks. I ended up using `in_the_loop`:

```
if (!in_the_loop()){
    return;
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Glad we were able to figure that out!

Comment: Thanks again, also side note : Whats up with the haters downvoting questions, seems a little abusive

Comment: You got it. Well, your original question lacked code, and this is a developer-centric site. Questions without code are generally undesirable. I know that code was added later, but perhaps it was too late. The answer you posted probably would have been better as a comment. Following the guidelines in the [help topics](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) will help make things better for everyone. Anyway, don't take it personally and welcome to WPSE :-)